# Get jQuery click, context (this) to output single object, not multiple

Tags: jquery, click, parent

So I do:

```
    $('.divs').bind('click', function()
    {
         console.log("clicked " +$(this).text());
    }
```

On:

```
    <DIV class="divs" id="parent1">Dad
      <DIV class="divs" id="child1">Kid1</DIV>
      <DIV class="divs" id="child2">Kid2</DIV>
    </DIV>
```

Then I get multiple outputs when I click on child1, like:

"clicked Kid1"

"clicked DadKid1Kid2"

on my console

Only when I click on the 'most parent' div i get a single output.
This is all pretty logical, but I'd like to only select the 'most child'-ish one only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop the propagation of the click event by using `event.stopPropagation`.

```
$('.divs').bind('click', function(event)
{
     event.stopPropagation();
     console.log("clicked " +$(this).text());
});
```

Notice I added `event` as an argument for the event handler anonymous function.

When you click an element it fires a click event, then that event bubbles up the DOM all the way to the `document` element, triggering a click event on each ancestor element from the original target to the `document` element. We can stop this event propagation however.

You can also `return false;` which in a jQuery Event Handler will `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('.divs').bind('click', function()
{
     console.log("clicked " +$(this).text()); 
     return false;
});
```

Some documentation for ya:

- `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation
- `event.preventDefault()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P5tXP/

Comment: Thanks, perfect! the return false one seems the cleanest to me, since they seem to do the same, I'll use that

Answer (score 0):

you can go through this site
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

events in javascript go through 3 phases capturing,at target and bubbling..

if you want to handle only at at target
you can do something like this

```
function handler(event){

  event.stopPropagation(); //cancel bubble for IE ,stops bubbling phase

  ele = event.target | event.srcElement;

  if(ele.id == "child1"){
     // your code
  }
}


you can also try using currentTarget and this in handler ..
```